# st_difference (erase overlapped feature) line from polygon

Tags: postgis, erase, st-difference

I have two layers.
One is MultiLineString and the other is MultiPolygon.

[image]

I am trying to erase lines that are on the polygon feature
With QGIS difference tool, it worked just fine

This is my code and I do not understand what is wrong with my query.
I do not see anything wrong.

```
select a.objectid, st_difference(a.geom, b.geom) as shape
from line a, mesh b
limit 500
```

The results return line segments  that are also in the mesh.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does a cross product between the line layer and the polygon layer. If you have 1 line and 2 polygon, the line being within the first polygon, you would still get two results: one with an empty geometry (line1-polygon1) and one with a full geometry (line1-polygon2).

If your dataset is not too big, you could aggregate all the polygons into one, and then compute the difference. I would also remove the lines that are completely within the polygon, and the polygons that don't intersect with the lines

The query would be similar to the following - untested - one:

```
SELECT a.objectid, st_difference(a.geom, b.geom) as shape
FROM line a, 
    LATERAL 
        (SELECT ST_COLLECT(m_single.geom) geom
        FROM 
            (SELECT (ST_DUMP(m.geom)).geom geom 
            FROM mesh m
            WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom,m.geom))m_single) b
WHERE ST_Within(a.geom, b.geom) = false
```

Comment: somehow the code gives me self-intersect error.
I st-union(ed) my mesh and executed the difference and it worked.
Thank you for your advice and comment!